# Matrix application of approxfun for faster linear interpolation

Tags: r, performance, apply, prediction

I have a data frame of values at measured dates for which I need to make a prediction/interpolation from to new dates in a large matrix. Currently, I am using `approxfun()` to create a new interpolation function, then I use `apply()` to each row in my matrix. The problem is, my matrix is quite large and `apply()` with `approxfun()` is slow. I will be using this in an optimization routine, so speed is  a concern. Also, the results of the `apply()` command will need to be transformed. Is there a better way to make interpolated predictions to each row of new data, without using `apply()` or similar? I also have new data outside of the range of original dates, so `approxfun()` takes care of this, but maybe there are other options?

```
library(microbenchmark)

# input data
Date <- c(2015, 2014.5, 2014, 2013.5, 2013, 2012.5, 2012, 2011.5, 2011)
CFC11 <- c(227.346, 228.718, 230.202, 231.419, 232.786, 234.177, 235.506, 236.463, 237.423)
Input <- data.frame(Date, CFC11)

# New Dates
Well1 <- c(2015.6, 2014.2, 2013.1)
Well2 <- c(2013.7, 2011.9, 2010)
NDates <- rbind(Well1, Well2)
NDates <- matrix(NDates, nrow = 2, ncol = 3)

# Input function
CFC11fun <- approxfun(Input$Date,Input$CFC11,rule=2)

# Apply the input function to the dates to get the input at the new dates 
# rowwise
# this transposes the result, so I would need to transpose it back
t(apply(NDates,1,CFC11fun))

# looks at timing
microbenchmark(t(apply(NDates,1,CFC11fun)), times = 1000, unit = "us")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call your function on the entire matrix, and shape the result into a matrix of the same dimensions:

```
matrix(CFC11fun(NDates), nrow=nrow(NDates))
```

Comment: This worked great and is faster! `microbenchmark(t(apply(NDates,1,CFC11fun)), matrix(CFC11fun(NDates), nrow=nrow(NDates)), times = 1000, unit = "us")`